# Sudden appearance of <NA> in R

Tags: r

I have two txt files :

pair1.txt

```
ida idb val
A   B   1
A   C   2
A   D   3
A   E   5
E   B   4
```

pair2.txt

```
ida idb type
A   B   x   
C   E   y
D   B   x
A   F   y
G   B   x
```

and I run the following script :

```
p1 = read.table("pair1.txt",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
p2 = read.table("pair2.txt",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

p1[,"type"]=NA
p2[,"val"]=NA
p2 = p2[,c("ida","idb","val","type")]

values = unique(c(p1[,1],p1[,2]))

for(i in 1:nrow(p2)){
    if ((p2[i,1] %in% values) && (p2[i,2] %in% values)) {
        p1[nrow(p1)+1,] = p2[i,]
    }
}
```

In the end I obtain a dataframe which has NA in some places and `<NA>` at other places. To be precise here is the dataframe I obtain :

```
ida idb val type
1   A   B   1 <NA>
2   A   C   2 <NA>
3   A   D   3 <NA>
4   A   E   5 <NA>
5   E   B   4 <NA>
6   A   B  NA    x
7   C   E  NA    y
8   D   B  NA    x
```

Anyone knows what causes this ? How Can I fix it ? Maybe more philosophical : which NA do I want ?

Comment: read `help(NA)`, you are looking at two kinds of NA, NA_character_ and NA_integer_

Comment: @brunk NA_character_ and NA_integer are both NA. The <NA> is because **type** is coerced into a factor in the code.

Comment: @kliron: actually is coerced to a character not a factor, anyway NAs in data.frame character columns are printed as  `<NA>`

Comment: To elaborate my comment, when you do `p1[,"type"]=NA` you are adding a column with `NA` of type logical (NA is of type logical). Then, when you add new rows, the column is automatically coerced to character since you're adding strings in that column. If you want, you can do `p1[,"type"]=NA_character_` or
`p1[,"type"]=as.character(NA)` to already initialize the type column to character (you will get `<NA>` from the beginning).

Comment: Thanks a lot @digEmAll ! This solution is fine for me but I wonder if maybe there is a way to get only NA's ?

Comment: `<NA>` is just another way to print a missing value for a character, but it's an `NA`...so for example if you do `is.na()` on those values you will get TRUE... do you need them printed as `NA` instead of `<NA>` for some particular reason ?

Comment: No not at all, if they are the same then it's fine with me :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @kliron yes, they are both NA, but NA is a generic with flavors for different classes (and it is character not factor here).  At the base level NA_character_  is a SEXP, whereas NA_integer_ is actually just defined as INT_MIN (2^31-1 I believe).

Comment: @bunk Thanks, I meant that the fact that they print as <NA> does not have to do with what you explain in your otherwise entirely correct post.

Comment: @kliron good point, I've overcomplicated this quite a bit ;)